# Cocos IDE Error Running Simulator

Tags: cocos2d-js

I've recently installed a Cocos IDE in my laptop and I've tried to use it but when I click the Win32Debug or compile my source code a dialog box will open, it says something like this:

Simulator E:/CocosProject/TestCocosJSGame\runtime/win32/PrebuiltRuntimeJs.exe can't run correctly; could be error with your simulator or it is blocked by firewall.

I've tried to allow the cocos code ide in my firewall but the error is still there.

The Cocos IDE works perfectly on the other laptop but on this one I think something is wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes! I found out that I currently installed Java 8 in my laptop and my buddy is using Java 7 so I installed Java 7 and it turned out that it runs perfectly! :)